# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Lewis Goddard]
[image: RolandiXor]
[image: Daniel Foré]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections upon site graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Great news. Congratulation to new Moderators.

Answer (score 9):

I just want to chime in and say thank you to everyone who decided to vote for me on that Meta post. I hope we have a great time together improving this community and helping people. If you're not okay with how some things are handled (for whatever reason), please let me know - I'm sure we can work something out to suit most community members.

Comment: +1 and embik is super communicative, always trying to keep a discussion going to get to a resolution.

Answer (score 8):

### Congratulations to my fellow mods!

Remember, with great power, comes a quote from Spiderman's uncle, and there is no try, only do, etc.

All jokes aside, I will try to be an active and useful moderator and serve the community well.

---

And as stated in my nomination, I do have awesome cat gifs, so here is one, as a token of my good will.

[image: ShouldHaveUsedelementaryFool]

What the cat said:

> Should Have Used elementary Fool!

Comment: What OS is that ?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but the icon theme looks to be KDE crystal, so it's likely KDE on some Linux or BSD distro.